# Array placeholder in Gherkin syntax

Tags: cucumber, bdd, gherkin

Hi I am trying to write express a set of requirements in gherkin syntax, but it requires a good deal of repetition. I saw [here](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Scenario-Outlines) that I can use placeholders which would be perfect for my task, however some of the data in my Given and in my then are collections. How would I go about representing collections in the examples?

```
Given a collection of spaces <spaces>
    And a <request> to allocate space
When I allocate the request
Then I should have <allocated_spaces>

Examples:
| spaces | request | allocated_spaces |
|  ?     |  ?      |  ?               |
```

Answer (score 5):

A bit hacky, but you can delimit a string:

```
Given a collection of spaces <spaces>
    And a <request> to allocate space
When I allocate the request
Then I should have <allocated_spaces>

Examples:
| spaces    | request | allocated_spaces |
|   a,b,c   |  ?      |  ?               |

Given(/^a collection of spaces (.*?)$/) do |arg1|
  collection = arg1.split(",")  #=> ["a","b","c"]
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Data Tables](https://cukes.info/step-definitions.html#data_tables). I never try to have param in data table before, but in theory it should work.

```
Given a collection of spaces:
| space1        |
| space2        |
| <space_param> |
And a <request> to allocate space
When I allocate the request
Then I should have <allocated_spaces>

Examples:
| space_param | request | allocated_spaces |
|  ?          |  ?      |  ?               |
```

The given data table would be an instance of [`Cucumber::Ast::Table`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/cucumber/Cucumber/Ast/Table), checkout the rubydoc for its API.

Comment: I've tested it right now and it worked. this should be the right answer. And better than user a rows I'd use columns.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example, again using split, but without the regex:

```
  Scenario Outline: To ensure proper allocation
    Given a collection of spaces <spaces>
      And a <request> to allocate space
     When I allocate the request
     Then I should have <allocated_spaces>

    Examples:
      | spaces       | request | allocated_spaces |
      | "s1, s2, s3" | 2       | 2                |
      | "s1, s2, s3" | 3       | 3                |
      | "s1, s2"     | 3       | 2                |
```

I use cucumber-js so this is what the code may look like:

```
Given('a collection of spaces {stringInDoubleQuotes}', function (spaces, callback) {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    this.availableSpaces = spaces.split(", ");
    callback();
});

Given('a {int} to allocate space', function (numToAllocate, callback) {
    this.numToAllocate = numToAllocate;
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    callback();
});

When('I allocate the request', function (callback) {
    console.log("availableSpaces:", this.availableSpaces);
    console.log("numToAllocate:", this.numToAllocate);
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    callback();
});

Then('I should have {int}', function (int, callback) {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    callback(null, 'pending');
});
```